# cURL upload to Google Drive

Tags: php, curl, upload, google-drive-api

I can create a file in Google Drive through a json into a Drive folder:

```
$data = array(
    "title" => $_FILES['file']['name'],
    "parents" => array(array(
        "kind" => "drive#parentReference",
        "id" => $parent_id
    )),
    "mimeType" => "application/pdf"
);
$data = json_encode($data);

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?oauth_token=".$accessToken;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

But I can't find a way to add the PDF file on it, since no json attribute is specified on Google Drive Documentation.

Where would I have to add the file contents?
Is this possible?

Do I have to upload the file to upload/drive and then the metadata with the folder id? I don't find the sense on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put the file in the body (i.e. in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS).  You'll want to specify Content-Type matching the file type and Content-Length as well.

This is [well documented](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads).

File metadata should be going to /drive/v2/files, not /upload/drive/v2/files.

This way, you'd have to make two requests.

If you want to do both a file and meta simultaneously, you can use the API and file insert:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Note that there's a [PHP library](https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads) to make this easier.

Comment: Yes, edited the path. The thing is, if i send the file contents, I don't find a way to send the parent folder's id or any other info on the file. Is the Title attribute that gets the file path?

Comment: I've tried using that library but can't get it working for some reason. The project was made on curl from the beginning, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it not working now on the library. It just shows Internal Server Error on my console at the moment i set the access token on the client. Do you know how to add the file in the curl way?

Comment: @mrq As mentioned above, if you're going to do it directly using the API, without using the convenience library, you'll need to do two transactions, one to put the file, and another to set the meta.  I'll try and update with a more detailed answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I've tried using the double curl call, but if i get the file on the postfields, i can't send the file id to upload it to. I've never done this before, I'm sorry if i seem too ignorant but I am at this. Thanks